# Cannot find JavaScript "Alignment" settings in IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.3

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea

I am completely new to IntelliJ IDEA (v 14.0.3), and am trying to update the Code Style settings. However, I have been unable to successfully update my JavaScript code style settings, specifically the "Alignment" settings. If I hit "Enter" to break up a line that is too long, I expect the editor to indent the new line. Unfortunately, that is not the case (as you can see by the second image).

[image: JavaScript Example]

The "Help" menu within IntelliJ gave me a screen that specifically listed a table of "Alignment" options, right after the "Keep when Reformatting" header. However, as noted by this screen, I cannot find the alignment heading.

[image: JavaScript Code Style Settings]

Does anyone know what settings I should adjust so that breaking up a long line of code will automatically indent the new line?

Thanks

Comment: I believe that is the 'normal' behavior as you're not actually adding 'a new line' your are simply `continuing a string declaration` to the next line. In most normal circumstances you don't indent a line-break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there - go to the `Tabs and Indents` tab and make sure, the value for `Continuation indent` is set to 4. This setting breaks my lines like you described.

If it doesn't work by pressing Enter but it works when reformatting the code (`Code > Reformat Code...`), make sure the following checkbox is checked:

`File > Settings > Editor > General > Smart Keys > Enter > Smart indent`

Comment: Unfortunately, I have tried that, and it still doesn't indent properly. There must be another setting that I inadvertently adjusted.

Comment: Is it aligned correctly, if you go to `Code > Reformat Code...`?

Comment: No. I have been trying that constantly, hoping that it will change :)

Comment: This might be a bug. If you replace `document....innerHtml` with `var very....longName`, it behaves correctly.

Comment: Realize that this was a long time ago, but thought I should mark it as answer as it worked for me after a re-install.